# Not able to access to site contents with PHP/CURL

Tags: php, curl

```
$ch2 = SSLCURL("https://www.tcpvpn.com/create-tcpvpn-account-server");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.tcpvpn.com/free-vpn-server-continent-europe");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "server=115");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$ex = curl_exec($ch2);
echo nl2br(str_replace("<","!!",$ex));
curl_close($ch2);
```

This is the code that I access to website. I handle cookies, SSL access, redirecting actions and UserAgent (Latest Chrome) on SSLCURL function.

The thing is when I access to that website over my browser or even with Glype (a proxy script written in PHP), I can reach to website without problem, but everytime I try to access over my script, I just get a meta redirection. How can I fix it?

edit: here comes the SSLCURL

```
function SSLCURL($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__)."/jamjar.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__)."/jamjar.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Accept-Language:tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
        "Connection:keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1"
        ));
    return $ch;
}
```

Comment: What the heck is `SSLCURL`? The php extension curl can handle SSL fine, there is no need for additional software/extensions.

Comment: It's my own function, the point is writing less code. There are working more curls in that php file, so I wanted to *shrink* my code.

Comment: what do you mean that you get a meta redirection? It seems to work ok with php-cli

Comment: @Fiil I'm not getting the "real" content.

Comment: At the very least, your POSTFIELDS are missing `username` and `password`.  Can't create an account with just a server ID.

Comment: @drew010 well, when you post "server", page returns the form that you can create account. I want to look like visited the page and then created the account.